# (PHP + PDO + Sqlite3) How to check query returned is null?

Tags: php, pdo

as shown above may i know is there a way to check a return query is null? which means it contains zero value.

I have the following sql query statements:

```
$result_number_country_malware = $db->query("SELECT sum(download_hits) as total_hits from date1_dcerpc; ");
```

so how do i check whether `$result_number_country_malware` is null? This is a PDO object, hence i can't use normal operators to check.

thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: `empty($result_number_country_malware)` ?

Comment: cant. $result_number_country_malware is an PDO object array. not a variable

Comment: `empty` works with arrays, next time check the manual first. http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: this array will always contain an SQL query. irregardless whether the query is returned null or not. Hence it will never be empty.

Comment: YUUPS I GOT IT ALRD! THANKS!!!!! :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

did you try $result_number_country_malware->count() ?

it would be similar to mysql_num_rows($result); if its 0 it is null, that being said..

if($result_number_country_malware->count()){
NOT NULL
}
else
{
NULL
}

I am not a PDO expert by any means, but i use doctrine and this seems very similar.

Comment: hmm could you give a more exact syntax of the statement?

Comment: this applies to mysql. i'm using sqlite :(

Comment: i did just find this on another site..

<?php 
$sQuery = "SELECT * FROM table"; 

$rResult = $pdo->query($sQuery)->fetchAll(); 
echo count($rResult);

Answer (score 1):

[`fetchColumn`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) for `SELECT` statements, [`rowCount`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) for `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `INSERT` statements.